# Solving recurrence relation in two variables and multinomial expansion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, recurrence-relations, alternative-proof, multinomial-coefficients

I just want to ask if there is a known result/proof for the given recurrence relation and multinomial expansion relationship.

The solution of the recurrence relation

$$f(m,k)=f(m-1,k)+af(m-1,k-1)+bf(m-1,k-2)+cf(m-1,k-3)$$

with initial condition $f(m,0)=1$ and $f(m,k)=0$ if $k\geq 3m+1$ is given by the $k^{th}-$term of the multinomial expansion of

$$(1+ax+bx^2+cx^3)^m.$$

I am successful in finding the solution of the recurrence of the form $f(m,k)=f(m-1,k)+af(m-1,k-1)$ given certain conditions using generating functions. However, trying to emulate the method for the problem above leads to a messy solution. So I am wondering if there are any available materials covering the problem above as a result. Or are there any possible methods to prove the problem above such that the method will provide a simple unmessy solution.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I would expect any closed form to be messy, though you can say $\sum\limits_k f(m,k) = (1+a+b+c)^m$

Comment: You need at least to give 2 other families of initial conditions $f(m,1)=..., f(m,2)=..., $. Otherwise your recurrence relationship will not work...

Comment: @JeanMarie, I want my recurrence such that $f(m,1)$ is equal to the numerical coefficient of $x$ in $P^m(x)$ while for $f(m,2)$, it must be equal to the coefficient of $x^2$ in $P^m(x)$ where $P(x)=1+ax+bx^2+cx^3$. Based on my computation it must be that $f(m,1)=ma$ and $f(m,2)$ is a complicated expression in terms of the variables $a$ and $b$.

Comment: But I want to say that based on your recurrence relationship (in its present state) and your initial conditions, which are supposed to work "stand alone" (**without reference to the polynomial**) how do you compute for example f(1,1), f(2,1), etc... ?